pandas groupby() gives me an error when trying to do numerical opperation on dataframes also containing strings
I'm new to pandas and I'm a bit confused about a difference concerning my output and the output seen in reference material.
Lets say I use groupby("something") on a dataframe which contains columns with numerical values as well as columns with object/str values.
In all the reference material I've seen so far, whenever there is a numeric operation run on such a group they get back a dataframe, where all the non numerical columns are simply left out. That is kinda handy.
But whenever I try the exact same thing (in VS Code, not a Jupyter Notebook), I get an error. I can avoid it, by specifying the wanted columns explicitly.
Here is an example:
df = pd.DataFrame([[543, "Aaa", "M"],
                   [654, "Bbb", "N"],
                   [65, "Ccc", "M"],
                   [465, "Ddd", "N"]],
                   columns=["X", "Y", "Z"])

group = df.groupby("Z").mean()
print(group)

gives me an error.
But:
df = pd.DataFrame([[543, "Aaa", "M"],
                   [654, "Bbb", "N"],
                   [65, "Ccc", "M"],
                   [465, "Ddd", "N"]],
                   columns=["X", "Y", "Z"])

group = df.groupby("Z").mean(["X"])
print(group)

gives the desired dataframe. In this example.
I know how to get what I need in this case. But still I'd like to know why this is. I'm quite new to this and have to rely on my reference material. But if i get errors on the stuff I'm tought, it gets kinda cumbersome.
Is this due to a new pandas version i use? Am I missing something?
I use Anaconda to launch my VScode. Everything should be pretty up to date. I use Windows 10 (in this case).
Thanks in advance.
Any hints are very welcome.

Edit: The question was, why is the used reference material doing stuff without getting an error, but I do get one with the exact same code.
(The question was not what the difference between .mean() and .sum() is.)
Thankfully @mozway already gave the very helpful answer. Thanks for that.
Short: Because the Reference is outdated (and eventually not so good).
Background: .mean(numeric_only=False) is the 'new' default since Pandas 2.0 (04 - 2023).
But it used to be .mean(numeric_only=_NoDefault.no_default)
<<< Just in case somebody is wondering about the same thing. >>>

You shouldn't rely on non-numeric columns being automatically discarded, the numeric_only parameter is False by default. Use df.groupby("Z").mean(numeric_only=True)

@mozway Thanks man. This is the answer that actually helps. Still curios about why the ref material does it. Maybe the default was True once? But nevermind. Will use numeric_only=True even though I wasn't thought like that.

Yes, the default changed in version 2, it used to behave like True previously.
